# If + Search + MID works for one string but not another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using one equation (so I can drag the equation down the column of 700+ rows) I want to extract a 3 digit number from one specific format and a four digit number from a second format.

Can anyone help me understand why this works for one string, but not the next?

```
=IF(SEARCH("Store 0*",C471),(MID(C471,8,3)),(MID(C471,7,4)))
```

> String 1: (working) "Store 0964 - Pharmacy Measurement Patient Matrix - May 1 2020 to Oct 31 2020 - Green Shield Canada.pdf"

> String 2: #Value! "Store 9500 - Pharmacy Measurement  - May 1 2020 to Oct 31 2020 - Green Shield Canada.pdf"

I realize that "Store 0" doesn't exist in the second string, but shouldn't that return the "Value if false" from the if statement?

Comment: The clue is in the beginning of your current formula >> `IF(SEARCH("Store 0*",C471)`. This will yield an error and won't automatically go to your `FALSE` parameter. Check for `ISNUMBER` too. Use `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Store 0*",C471)),(MID(C471,8,3)),(MID(C471,7,4)))`. That being said, can't you just use `=--MID(C471,7,4)`?

Comment: That's great! Yet, I think you can simplify the whole thing drastically.

Comment: You are right, Mid (7,4) will work and much more simple, but I don't want the leading 0 when the number is 0512, etc. Thanks again!

Comment: Have another good look at the last line of my very first comment =)

Comment: I saw it but didn't try it..  <<hangsheadinshame>> Thank you VM Sir. ;)